# creating self join which uses inner join , My requirement is delete same rows from it_med_t which are returned by the self join

Tags: oracle12c

Delete rows using self join.

Here is my query :

```
    SELECT  e1.I_NO FROM
        it_med_t e1
    INNER JOIN it_med_t e2 ON
        e1.MED_REL_NO <> e2.MED_REL_NO
      and (( e1.DEL_DATE is null and  e2.DEL_DATE is not null) or ( e2.DEL_DATE is null and  e1.DEL_DATE is not null))
        AND e1.MED_NO = e2.MED_NO
        AND e1.I_NO = e2.I_NO
        where e1.DEL_DATE is not null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ROWID, It solved my problem.

DELETE FROM it_med_t 
WHERE  ROWID IN (SELECT e1.ROWID 
                 FROM   it_med_t e1 
                        inner join it_med_t e2 
                                ON e1.med_rel_no <> e2.med_rel_no 
                                   AND ( ( e1.del_date IS NULL 
                                           AND e2.del_date IS NOT NULL ) 
                                          OR ( e2.del_date IS NULL 
                                               AND e1.del_date IS NOT NULL ) ) 
                                   AND e1.med_no = e2.med_no 
                                   AND e1.i_no = e2.i_no 
                 WHERE  e1.del_date IS NOT NULL);